# How to do the integral $\int e^{-\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

I need to compute the integral

$$
\int e^{-\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}}dx
$$

but I don't know how to do it. I have (unsuccesfully) tried with Mathematica and searched it in the Gradshtein.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the context of the integral?

Comment: i think no solution in the known elementary function can be find

Comment: It seems not to have a closed form.  Why do you need it?

Comment: with the right limits a definite integral might have closed form in terms of Bessels, but for the indefinite case, no way!

Comment: Integrals with the exponential of a nonlinear function "smell".

Comment: By a linear change of variable, you can reduce to $e^{-\sqrt{t^2\pm d^2}}$, which is asymptotic to $e^{-t}$.

Comment: Assuming $a>0$, @YvesDaoust. If $a<0$ then the integrand is only defined on a finite interval (at most) and thus has no asymptote.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: then it's asymptotic to $e^{it}$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust What do they smell like?

Comment: @RobertIsrael: a smell of Liouville's theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the substitution $t = \sqrt{a} x + b/(2 \sqrt{a})$, this becomes
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \int e^{-\sqrt{t^2 + d}}\; dt $$
where $d = c - b^2/(4a)$.  Then with $s = \sqrt{t^2 + d}$ it becomes 
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \int \frac{e^{-s} s}{\sqrt{s^2-d}}\; ds$$

Still no closed form, but for $\sqrt{|d|} < s$ we can expand the integrand in a series in powers of $d$:

$$ \dfrac{e^{-s} s}{\sqrt{s^2-d}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2k)!}{k!^2} \left(\frac{d}{4s^2} \right)^k e^{-s}$$

And then we can integrate term-by-term using the incomplete Gamma function.  Your antiderivative becomes

$$\frac{-1}{\sqrt{a}} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2k)!}{k!^2} \left(\frac{d}{4}\right)^k \Gamma(1-2k,s) $$

EDIT:
Note that this converges absolutely for $\sqrt{|d|} < s$, since
$$ \Gamma(1-2k,s) = \int_s^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{t^{2k}}\; dt < 
\frac{1}{s^{2k}} \int_s^\infty e^{-t}\; dt = \frac{e^{-s}}{s^{2k}}$$
and the series for $s/\sqrt{s^2-d}$ converges in this region as
$s/\sqrt{s^2-d}$ is analytic in $d$ there.

Comment: Following up on the edit, it seems worth noting that $\sqrt{|d|}<s=\sqrt{t^2+d}\implies |d|<t^2+d$. If $d>0$ i.e. $ax^2+bx+c=0$ only has imaginary roots then this is satisfied for all $t>0$. On the other hand, if $d<0$ then the above constraint becomes $|d|<t^2-|d|\implies t^2>2|d|$. Hence when $ax^2+bx+c$ has real roots then the series expansion is not convergent for small $t$ and should not be used for that purpose. (Of course, if there are real roots then the square root won't be defined for all real $x$ and therefore one should expect problems regardless.)